# Flask server timeouts at 30 sec with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Here is the minimal example of the code. curl request `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_zip/my_zip.zip -o my_zip.zip` should send user the file `archive/my_zip.zip`

It works correctly without `gunicorn` and disconnects after 30 seconds, when the server is  launched with `gunicorn`.

```
from os import path
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_zip/<file_path>', methods=['GET'])
def get_zip(file_path):  # file_path: path to a large zip file
    return send_file(path.join('archive', file_path), as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000", debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

What is the correct way to fix this disconnect when ran under gunicorn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

30 seconds is default `timeout` value for gunicorn.

To increase it use `--timeout <seconds>` parameter on your gunicorn config.

Also if you run gunicorn under nginx, don't forget to manage nginx's settings:

```
proxy_connect_timeout <seconds>s;
proxy_read_timeout <seconds>s;
```

**UPDATE:**

it's better and safer to send files from flask by using [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory)